# Extract (or isolate) 'group-wise constant' columns from a data frame, *using dplyr/tidyverse*

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

How can I extract (or isolate_ group-wise constant columns from a data frame, *using dplyr/tidyverse*?

This is an update of Dowle/Hadley's decades-old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647006/efficiently-locate-group-wise-constant-columns-in-a-data-frame). The earlier poster's example...

Using a contrived example from iris (to generate a dataset with columns that are constant by group for this example )

```
irisX <- iris %>% mutate(
    numspec = as.numeric(Species),
    numspec2 = numspec*2
)
```

Now I want to generate a dataset that keeps the columns `Species`, `numspec`, and `numspec2` only (and keeps only one row for each).

*And I don't want to have to tell it which columns these are (constant by group) -- I want it to find these for me.*

So what I want is

```
Species, numspec, numspec2
setosa, 1, 2
versicolor, 2, 4
virginica, 3, 6
```

Unlike in the older linked question I want to do something using the tidyverse so I can understand it better and the code looks cleaner.

I tried something like

```
single_iris <- irisX %>% 
group_by(Species) %>% 
select_if(function(.) n_distinct(.) == 1)
```

But the latter `select_if` ignores the groupings.

Comment: One problem with `n_distinct(.) == 1` is it is not matching 1 within `select`, but the whole group n_disitnct, so it is 3.  May be a bug.  according to `?select` `Groups are maintained; you can't select off grouping variables.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use `select`, do it outside the grouping

```
library(dplyr)
irisX %>%
     select(where(~ n_distinct(.) == n_distinct(irisX$Species))) %>%     
     distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this misses the point slightly: I want the code to *select* the columns that have this property of being constant within groups. I don't want to have to enter this myself. (I'll re-word)

Comment: @daaronr Based on what you showed, you may need `cur_group()` (updated the post)

Comment: This gets what I want ... a subset of your answer above:


`irisX %>% select(where(~ n_distinct(.) == n_distinct(irisX$Species))) %>% distinct()`


Should we erase or move the rest of your answer and then I can accept it as the correct one?

Comment: @daaronr okay.  nice to know that

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(dplyr)
irisX %>% 
group_by(Species) %>%
summarise(across(everything(), n_distinct)) %>% 
select_if(function(.) n_distinct(.) == 1)
```

Output:

```
   A tibble: 3 × 2
   numspec numspec2
     <int>    <int>
 1       1        1
 2       1        1
 3       1        1
```

You could also extract the column names as a vector and use for other "tidy-selection" purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species)%>%
  summarise(numspec = as.numeric(first(Species)),
            numspec2 = numspec*2)
```

Comment: Also thanks but maybe I could have worded this better (I fixed it).  The top part was just to demonstrate an example dataset. Suppose I *have* a dataset with *many* such constant-by-group columns (but I don't know which ones) and I want to isolate them.